# create automatic datetime when update the data in postgresql(phppgadmin)

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

create automatic datetime(date with timestamp) when update the data in postgresql(phppgadmin) on database table

Plese advise me
thanks

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Comment: i am asking like mysql current timestamp

Comment: Create a trigger (and of course the trigger function) like a_horse_with_no_name already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

1.if you use timestamp type in the column when you update the record then date time also updated
2.if you use varchar type in the column when you fire a query

**demo**

$sql = "update `table_name` set `field_name`=now() where your condition";

Comment: i am asking database update the field not a parameter